# using jquery to show updates

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

I am having some 8 products/services and i want to show updates based on the users who have used the services like

```
Product 1
smith used this service 8 hours ago

Product 2
neo used this service 10 hours ago
```

Now I have fetched the list of users with time and populated as a list

```
product 1
<ul class="ncls">
<li>Smith used this service 10 hours ago</li>
<li>Trinity used this service 11 hours ago</li>
<li>Morpheus used this service 12 hours ago</li>
</ul>

Product 2
<ul class="ncls">
<li>Neo used this service 3 hours ago</li>
<li>Oracle used this service 2 years ago</li>
</ul>
```

I am attempting to write a jquery script that would show one item from the list then fade it and show the next one.

So far i have done this, which doesnt work. So any ideas on how i can get this to work.

```
$(".ncls").children().hide().eq(0).show();
        (function showThisTat(){
            $('.ncls li:visible').delay(1500).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                  $(this).appendTo(this);
                  $('.ncls li:first').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                      showThisTat();
                  });
            });
        })();
```

Comment: Do you want to show 2 separate "streams" of notifications (2 notification boxes) or 1 stream that cycles through product 1 and then moves on to product 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this you can mess with the settings as you see fit: you may want to set a min-height on the ul so it doesn't jump up and down. http://jsfiddle.net/vt5u6/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var lists = $(".ncls");
    var listsLength = lists.length;
    var rotateDelay = 3500;
    var fadeDelay = 444;

    function swapItems(theList) {
        var current = theList.find("li:visible");
        current.fadeOut();
        if (current.next("li").length == 0) {
            theList.find("li").eq(0).delay(fadeDelay).fadeIn()
        } else {
            current.next("li").delay(fadeDelay).fadeIn();
        }
    }

    function createRotatingList(theList) {
        var listItems = theList.find("li");
        var listItemsLength = listItems.length;

        for (j = 0; j < listItemsLength; j++) {
            listItems.eq(j).hide();
        }

        listItems.eq(0).show();

        setInterval(function() {
            swapItems(theList)
        }, rotateDelay)


    }

    for (i = 0; i < listsLength; i++) {
        createRotatingList(lists.eq(i))
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).appendTo(this);` ?

Maybe;

```
$(".ncls").children().hide().eq(0).show();
    (function showThisTat(){
        $('.ncls li:visible').delay(1500).fadeOut('slow',function(){
              $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
              $('.ncls li:first').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                  showThisTat();
              });
        });
    })();
```

Noting `$(this).parent()`

**Edit**

Thinking about this more, thanks to Greg, the showThisTat() will be firing twice each 1500ms, growing exponentially.  Also, the first line *may* only work on the first list.  So, here is an edit;

```
$(".ncls").children().hide();
$(".ncls").children(":first-child").show();

    (function showThisTat(list){
        (list ?? $('.ncls li:visible')).delay(1500).fadeOut('slow',function(){
              var currentList = $(this).parent();
              $(this).appendTo(currentList);
              $('.ncls li:first').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                  showThisTat(currentList);
              });
        });
    })();
```

Comment: This is closer (this.parent needs to be $(this).parent, mind you) but the problem is still the two lists. It's going to cycle through product 1 and ignore product 2.

Comment: @GregPettit yep, had already fixed the `$(this).parent()`.  The showThisTat() function *should* run on both lists, as they would both be selected by the jQuery selector.  Not sure about the first line though.